# Why does Resharper complain when I compare a double to zero?

Tags: c#, floating-point, resharper

If I do

```
double d = 0;
if (d == 0) {
  ...
}
```

Resharper complains at the comparison `d == 0` about "Comparison of floating point number with equality operator. Possible loss of precision while rounding values."

Why? It cannot be difficult to represent exact zero as a double or a float can it?

I understand such a warning would be relevant if I compared to some other value such as 0.2 for which there is no exact binary representation.

Comment: I have no idea, but what happens if you compare `if (d == 0.0)`? would be more useless, but would be double & double.

Comment: please remove more useless tags like zero and add your language. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Resharper does not analyze how the double variable got its value.

After a few calculations a double value is rarely exact so resharper warns you that comparing a double with an exact value is not a good idea.

```
double x = Math.Sqrt(2);
double d = x * x;

Console.WriteLine(d == 2);
```

Answer (score 10):

[Since R# 6, many such inspections have a 'Why is ReSharper suggesting this?' item](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/03/resharper-enhances-suggestions-with-explanations/) on their Alt+Enter menu. In this case, [the explanation relates to the possible unintended consequences of doing equality comparisons on floating point values](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Compare+of+float+numbers+by+equality+operator):

> Using the `==` operator to compare floating-point numbers is, generally,
>   a bad idea. The problem arises from the fact that, typically, results
>   of calculations have to be ‘fitted’ into floating-point
>   representation, which does not always matched the perceived reality of
>   what result *should* be produced.

Answer (score 4):

often calculation with double is inexact. comparing a double with an exact value may be problematic. Comparing with an intervallmight be more secure.

```
if ((d > -0.000001) && (d < +0.000001)) {
   ...
}
```

the same applies when comparing dates

```
if ((date >= DateTime.parse("2012-05-21T00:00:00")) && 
   (date <= DateTime.parse("2012-05-21T23:59:59"))) {
}
```