# unable to filter records in the test methods as its complaining of AND operator in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to write test methods in my c#.net web api application. I need to filter the records from the given object of values and need to use and operator. For some reason it is not liking the and operator since i am using float values.Could somebody tell me what the problem could be ? Please note both are float datatypes

The error message is Equality comparison of floating point numbers. Possible loss of precision while rounding values

```
    private const float FrontedCoveragePolicyTypeId = 2 ;
    private const float DirectlyWrittenCoveragePolicyTypeId = 1;
    private const float Is953DYes = 1;
    private const float Is953DNo = 0; 

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetFedExciseExpenses_OnShore_Fronted_Test()
    {
        var result = _sut.GetFedExciseTaxExpenses(Industryid, DomicileId);
        Assert.IsTrue(result.Any());
        var fedExciseExpense = result.Find(x => x.CoveragePolicyTypeId == FrontedCoveragePolicyTypeId && x.Is953D == Is953DNo);
        AssertFedExciseExpense(fedExciseExpense);
    }

     private static void AssertFedExciseExpense(FedExciseExpense expense)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(expense);
        Assert.IsNotNull(expense.Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, expense.Value);
    }
```

Comment: "it is not liking the and operator" - what does that mean? Compiler error? Warning? Runtime error? Something else?

Comment: You mentioned float values, but all I can see are int values.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have updated the post. Its a warning and not error message. Do I need to change something. I have updated the post with the warning message too

Comment: Just change all your `private const float` to `private const int`. Why are they floats in the first place?

Comment: I agree with you but whoever designed the database has set those to columns to float and hence using it. The change to the datatype is not in our control as its done by a remote team.

Comment: Well then you can google "C# Possible loss of precision while rounding values" and find hundreds of matches (including this site) explaining what is this warning about. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10684365/5311735